# PhpStorm PSR-4 namespace fix suggestions for vendor

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, phpstorm

I create company vendor libs but have problem with namespaces.
Usually I ignore this but want now fix problems.

I test now example vendor `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle` but this have same errors.

[image]

When I create a new file I have suggested

[image]

How can I configure PhpStorm to suggest correct namespace?

Perhaps from vendor composer.json? It has:

```
  "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\": "" },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have custom classes, your need to configure PSR4 namespaces in composer.json.
You must not create your classes directly in vendor dir, because it can be override when you update dependencies.

For exemple, if you have custom classes in src/ with namespace **Kernel** :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Kernel\\": "src/" }
}
```

Comment: This was example, i create files in my vendors, solution that You provide work. But this is tiring -  for every my verdor i must add 
 "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:... 

then 
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "My\\Bundle\\TestBundle\\": "vendor/My/... }
}
I don't understand why We can't use composer.json in a bundle (allow add loc), this file has this entry after all

Comment: If you use custom vendors, you don't need to add psr4 config for each vendor, because each of your vendors has his composer.json with his psr4 config, then composer will autoload it automatically

Comment: Yes, thats correct but PHPStorm dont use this composer.json - show it as namespace error and when I create it suggest wrong namespace. Is possible to tell PHPStorm to use vendor namespace composer.json ?

Comment: My PHPStorm automatically does that, without any config. But you can take a look in preferences, then search for composer, you will find a field for path to composer.json if PHPStorm doesnt detect it automatically, maybe it can fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to **unmark** `vendor` folder as `Source Root`

Answer (score 0):

I make packages and have a similar work-flow as the question's author.

1. private git repo for package(s)
2. project level composer.json > repositories node.
3. use git inside vendor/my-brand/my-package

I use phpStorm.

I had the same issue.  The vendor///composer.json > autoload>psr-4>stuff was not being recognized properly by storm's code inspections.  My package namespace kept getting highlighted with fix recommendations.

SOLUTION: Do **not** select any of your package work nor your vendor brand as Preferences>Directories>"Sources".